# Gradle Kotlin DSL Replace Token

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

In my code there is `const val VERSION = $version`.
I want to replace `$version` with real version string which is in my `build.gradle.kts`.
How can I do this?

Comment: normally - application code is written to read such info from properties files. Gradle (or any build tool) supports via processResources where such tokens can be replaced.  Trying to do that in code is not normal - you can but gets you into trouble of generated code and then same class name problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_gradle/tree/master/kotlin/egg_StackOverflow_64840430).

One way is to use a template file (stored outside of `src` tree). Let's call it `TemplateVersion.kt`:

```
class Version() {
    val version = "__VERSION";
}
```

and then in `build.gradle.kts`, as initial part of the `compileKotlin` task, we generate `Version.kt` from `TemplateVersion.kt`:

```
val sourceFile = File(rootDir.absolutePath + "/resources/TemplateVersion.kt")
val propFile = File(rootDir.absolutePath + "/gradle.properties")
val destFile = File(rootDir.absolutePath + "/src/main/kotlin/${targetPackage}/Version.kt")

tasks.register("generateVersion") {
    inputs.file(sourceFile)
    inputs.file(propFile)
    outputs.file(destFile)

    doFirst {
        generateVersion()
    }
}

tasks.named("compileKotlin") {
    dependsOn("generateVersion") 
}

fun generateVersion() {
    val version: String by project
    val rootDir: File by project

    val inputStream: InputStream = sourceFile.inputStream()

    destFile.printWriter().use { out -> 
        inputStream.bufferedReader().forEachLine { inputLine ->
            val newLine = inputLine.replace("__VERSION", version)
            out.println(newLine) 
        }
    }

    inputStream.close()
}
```

where `gradle.properties` is:

```
version=5.1.50
```

It is trivially easy to add more fields to `Version.kt`, such as a build-timestamp.

(**Edit:** This has been updated with a proper `generateVersion` task that will detect changes to `gradle.properties`. The `compileKotlin` task will invoke this task).

Comment: Thank you so much. Have a nice day :D